# how do you specify an embedded column as an id whose reference contains an id in JPA

Tags: jpa

I'd like to build a structure where an embeddable is used as both an id and a regular embed. It's a base class use in many other tables and in some tables its both an id and a regular embed. I can't seem to get the right annotations between the classes. In the VCenterDatastore class.

If I specify `@EmbeddedId` on the `VCenterManagedObjectReference id` field, I get

```
org.cru.cloud.management.core.repository.managedobjectReference.
VCenterManagedObjectReference 
must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId: 
    org.cru.cloud.management.core.repository.datastore.VCenterDatastore.id
```

If I specify it as an `@Embedded` in the `VCenterDatastore` class, then I get

```
No identifier specified for entity: 
    org.cru.cloud.management.core.repository.datastore.VCenterDatastore".
```

The ManagedObjectReference class is provided via an external API

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ManagedObjectReference {
    public String val;
    public String type;

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String get_value() {
        return val;
    }

    public void set_value(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

The MOR class is my Serializable implementation of the ManagedObjectReference

```
@Embeddable
public class MOR implements Serializable
{
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String val;
    public String getVal() {return this.val;}
    public void setVal(String val) {this.val = val;}

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String type;
    public String getType() {return this.type;}
    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}

    public MOR(ManagedObjectReference managedObjectReference)
    {
        this.val = managedObjectReference.val;
        this.type = managedObjectReference.type;
    }
}
```

The VCenterManagedObjectReference was designed to be the entity representing the MOR. This was because I needed a way to retrieve the MOR if it already existed so that I wouldn't produced duplicate objects. Thus the getManagedObjectReference method. This class is used in many places both as an id and a regular "column".

```
@Embeddable
public class VCenterManagedObjectReference implements Serializable
{
    @Transient
    private ManagedObjectReference managedObjectReference;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MOR id;
    public MOR getId() {return this.id;}
    public void setId(MOR id) {this.id = id;}

    public VCenterManagedObjectReference() {}

    public VCenterManagedObjectReference(VCenterManagedObjectReference managedObjectReference)
    {
        this.id = managedObjectReference.id;
    }

    private VCenterManagedObjectReference(ManagedObjectReference managedObjectReference)
    {
        this.managedObjectReference = managedObjectReference;
    }

    public void populate() { }

    public static VCenterManagedObjectReference getManagedObjectReference(ManagedObjectReference managedObjectReference)
    {
        MOR mor = new MOR(managedObjectReference);
        VCenterManagedObjectReferenceRepository repository = VCenterManagedObjectReferenceRepositoryManagedObjectReferenceDetailsService.vCenterDatacenterRepository;
        VCenterManagedObjectReference vCenterManagedObjectReference = repository.findById(mor);
        return (vCenterManagedObjectReference == null)?new VCenterManagedObjectReference(managedObjectReference):vCenterManagedObjectReference;
    }
}
```

The VCenterDatastore class is an example of a class to reflect the data retrieved from the Datastore object which is, like the ManagedObjectReference class, provided by an external API.

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="datastore")
public class VCenterDatastore
{
    @Transient
    private Datastore datastore;

    @Embedded
    private VCenterManagedObjectReference id;
    public VCenterManagedObjectReference getId() {return this.id;}
    public void setId(VCenterManagedObjectReference id) {this.id = id;}

    ...
}
```

Comment: Firstly, MyEmbeddable should not have either '@Entity' or '@Table' annotations.

Comment: Although I can understand that, it doesn't yet change the symptoms.

Comment: Okay, you should update your code to reflect this and expand on 'it complains something to the effect' - maybe by posting the full error message.

Comment: If `MOR` class represents compound primary key, then `VCenterManagedObjectReference` class should be an entity class embeddable types have no identity (no PK from a database point of view).

Comment: Ouch! I was doing that to avoid creating a duplicate MOR which was another problem I was running into. In my initial load I may run across an entity (which is keyed by the MOR) more than once and I needed a way to detect that. The getManagedObjectReference exists to find an existing entity and return that rather then creating a new instance. Unfortunately, since the original ManagedObjectReference is not Serializable, I couldn't use that directly. The only way I had to do the findById(MOR) was to create a new MOR based on the ManagedObjectReference. ...

Comment: That seemed to cause persistence of multiple copies of the same MOR.